# How to Count tickets as DateWise

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query regarding my report, the report format is as under

```
**Date**           **Received**        **Closed**        **Pending**  
12/01/10              1000                 900               100
12/02/10              2000                1000              1000
12/03/10              1500                1300               200
```

The above report shows the Help Desk tickets Received, Closed, Pending Count as date wise.

How can I create a dynamic SQL query to show above result?

- Received Tickets is calculated on SubmitedDate
- Closed Tickets is calculated on ClosedDate with status "Closed"
- same for Pending Tickets whose status is "Pending".

Please provide me the idea or some sample SQL queries.

Comment: can you post your table structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the received, closed, and pending queries separately, and then join them together like this:

```
SELECT r.[Date], r.Count As Received, c.Count As Closed, p.Count AS Pending
FROM
   ( /* Received query here */ ) r
FULL JOIN 
   ( /* Closed query here */) c ON c.[Date] = r.[Date]
FULL JOIN
   ( /* Pending query here */) p ON p.[Date] = r.[Date]
```

I chose a full join because you wouldn't want a zero-result at any point to ever force a row to be culled from the results.

Comment: Thanks Joel, Its works perfectly. But only thing is query take time to display data because date wise selection if i select Jan to Dec then query takes 3 mins but display the right data.

Comment: @Iftikhar If you currently store exact timestamps, you can improve performance by adding computed columns to your table to store the closed/pending/submitted dates only (zeroed-out time portion for the column).  This way, sql server pre-computes the most expensive part of your query at insert time.

Comment: Hi Joel, i am using view for fetching the status data from database because in service desk system there are many types of jobs like incident, problem, task, work order these jobs is saved in various tables so what i can do here i create the four views for incident, problem, task, workorder and then create one view for collectively get all information of jobs. In the said query i used this view for getting the data. So please keep this scenario and then tell me what the best way to improve performance.  I

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, t.submitteddate, 101) AS [date].
         COUNT(t.submitteddate) AS received
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.status = 'closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS closed,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.status = 'pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pending
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, t.submitteddate, 101)
ORDER BY [date]
```

If you want to see dates where none were sold, you're going to have to derive a table of dates and then LEFT JOIN the query above to that based on the date.